# "Using unpublished class" Eclipse warning

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting the following warning message from Eclipse (yellow triangle near the code):

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Using unpublished class 
  package.SomeInterface
- Using unpublished class 
  package.SomeClass
```

Couldn't find references to the error message using search engines.
Any ideas?

Edited:
The class is public. The code is compiling and executing without any issues.

Comment: Add your code please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've declared as private your class, you should post your code

```
public class SomeInterface{
...
code
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code.

However the class is public, moreover the code compiles and runs without any errors.